# Flutter Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget But still work

Tags: flutter, firebase, exception, firebase-realtime-database

HOMEPAGE

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final stream = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('sensor/').onValue;

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final data = snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
                  if (data == null) {
                    return Text('No data');
                  }
                  final sensorEC = data['EC'];
                  final sensorPH = data['PH'];
                  final sensorRTD = data['RTD'];
                  final humidity = data['humidity'];
                  final temperature = data['temperature'];
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, left: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "SHOWCASE",
                              style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: bold),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.account_circle,
                              size: 30,
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 110,
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                "Water Management",
                                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  ParamWaterManagement(
                                    nameSensor: 'EC',
                                    valueSensor: '$sensorEC',
                                  ),
                                  ParamWaterManagement(
                                      nameSensor: 'PH',
                                      valueSensor: '$sensorPH'),
                                  ParamWaterManagement(
                                      nameSensor: 'RTD',
                                      valueSensor: '$sensorRTD'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 200,
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                "Water Climate",
                                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  ParamWaterClimate(
                                    nameSensor: 'humidity',
                                    valueSensor: '$humidity',
                                  ),
                                  ParamWaterClimate(
                                      nameSensor: 'temperature',
                                      valueSensor: '$temperature'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error.toString());
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                }

                return Text('....');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

WIDGET WATER MANAGEMENT

```
class ParamWaterManagement extends StatelessWidget {
  final String nameSensor;
  final String valueSensor;

  ParamWaterManagement({Key? key, required this.nameSensor, required this.valueSensor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 110,
      height: 55,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 7,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '$nameSensor (μS/cm)',
                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: bold,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 6,
            ),
            Text(
              '$valueSensor',
              style: neonBasicStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: 17,
                fontWeight: bold,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

WIDGET WATERCLIMATE

```
class ParamWaterClimate extends StatelessWidget {
  final String nameSensor;
  final String valueSensor;

  ParamWaterClimate({Key? key, required this.nameSensor, required this.valueSensor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      width: 120,
      height: 55,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 7,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "$nameSensor (μS/cm)",
                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: bold,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 6,
            ),
            Text(
              '$valueSensor',
              style: neonBasicStyle.copyWith(
                fontSize: 17,
                fontWeight: bold,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another exception was thrown:

> Incorrect use of Parent Data Widget flutter for details

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove Expended Widget from Text**

```
 Expanded(
  child: Text(
    $nameSensor (μS/cm)',
    style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: bold,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  ),
```

),

if not working then remove expended widget from Column

```
 Expanded(
      child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            "$nameSensor (μS/cm)",
            style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: bold,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 6,
        ),
        Text(
          '$valueSensor',
          style: neonBasicStyle.copyWith(
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: bold,
            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          ),
        )
      ]),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because you are using expanded widget directly inside padding widget in `ParamWaterClimate` class.
Remove expanded widget and it will not leave any error behind.

```
class ParamWaterClimate extends StatelessWidget {
 final String nameSensor;
 final String valueSensor;

 const ParamWaterClimate(
  {super.key, required this.nameSensor, required this.valueSensor});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    width: 120,
    height: 55,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 7),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    color: Colors.grey,
    ),
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
   child: Column(
     children: [
       Expanded(
         child: Text(
          "$nameSensor (μS/cm)",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 6),
      Text(valueSensor)
    ],
  ),
 );
}
}
```

Hope it helps.